# Mandar el valor 1 si es true, y si es false mandar el valor 0 al momento de guardar, en javascript con c#

Tags: javascript, c#

Buen día tengo una validacion en javascript que lo que hace es validar si es 1, chequea checkbox y si es 0 no lo chequea, es la siguiente:

```
<div class="space-4"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Valor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        @Html.CheckBox("IsActive", Model.Valor == "1" ? true : false, new { id = "chkValor"})
                        @*<div id='error_Habilita' name='error_Habilita'>&nbsp;</div>*@
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Pero ahora lo que necesito es, que si es true me manda a guardar el valor 1 y si es false me mande a guardar el valor 0, quice hacerlo dentro del mismo checkbox pero no me funciono, ahora quice hacerlo en mi controller con c# de esta manera pero no me funciona

```
 public JsonResult GuardarSolicitudParamCAT(ParametrosCATViewModels guardarSolicitudParamCAT)
    {
        Mensaje mensaje = new Mensaje();
        ParametrosCATBC parametrosCATBC = new ParametrosCATBC();

        bool valor = true;

        try
        {
            guardarSolicitudParamCAT.Valor(valor ? '1' : '0');
            guardarSolicitudParamCAT.Solicitante = Session["IdUsuario"].ToString();
            parametrosCATBC.SaveSolicitudParamCAT(guardarSolicitudParamCAT, new Bitacora { PerfilUsuario = Session["Perfil"].ToString(), Usuario = Session["IdUsuario"].ToString() });
         
            mensaje.Success = true;
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            mensaje.Success = false;
            mensaje.ErrorMessage = exception.Message.ToString();
        }
        return Json(mensaje, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Espero puedan apoyarme de favor

Answer (score 0):

lo que estoy viendo es que en el controlador estar validando el dato

```
guardarSolicitudParamCAT.Valor(valor ? '1' : '0');
```

cuando tendrias que validar el valor que llega en el modelo

```
guardarSolicitudParamCAT
```

es decir algo asi como

```
guardarSolicitudParamCAT.chkValor == false ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Buen día no funciono, más bien me marca error la línea

Comment: Coloca un punto de interrupción, en donde recibes tu entidad(ParametrosCATViewModels), verifica las propiedades que tiene hasta ese momento, verifica que el campo con el nombre del checkbox este recibiéndose y tenga un valor, en caso de que no asígnale el nombre al checkbox igual que en el modelo.